# Derivative of function between sets of matrices

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, manifolds

> Let $M_{k,n}$ be the set of all $k\times n$ matrices, $S_k$ be the set of all symmetric $k\times k$ matrices, and $I_k$ the identity $k\times k$ matrix. Let $\phi:M_{k,n}\rightarrow S_k$ be the map $\phi(A)=AA^t$. Show that $I_k$ is a regular value of this map.

By definition, I need to show that for every matrix $P$ such that $PP^t=I_k$, $\phi$ is a submersion at $P$. That is, $D\phi(P)$ is surjective.

But I'm not sure what the domain and range of $D\phi(P)$ should be. Normally when I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^s\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^t$, and any point $x\in\mathbb{R}^s$, I have $Df(x):\mathbb{R}^s\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^t$ being a $t\times s$ matrix. Here the function $\phi$ is from $M_{k,n}\rightarrow S_k$. What should $D\phi(P)$ look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D\phi_A:H\in M_{k,n}\rightarrow HA^T+AH^T\in S_k$. According to my post in
[Map to symmetric matrices is surjective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557680/map-to-symmetric-matrices-is-surjective),
if $A$ has maximal rank ($rank(A)=k$), then $A$ is not singular. Then the $k\times k$ matrices that are SPD are all regular values of $\phi$.